# android: Listview loading slow with abslistview

Tags: android, android-listview

i did a text with image which are loading from a xml file(.xml) and i followed this tutorial: (http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/ and http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/). the problem is i'm getting these two messages flooded in my logcat each time i run the app on Samsung S3 and it seriously makes the page load very slow (i tried on Samsung S2, Sony and Nexus: no problem).

```
D/AbsListView(24652): Get MotionRecognitionManager

D/AbsListView(24652): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener] I/MotionRecognitionManager(24652):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, listener=android.widget.AbsListView$4@430458c8
```

another point is, i didn't use the abslistview in my code at all and no scrollview as well.
anyone knows what is the problem here? will provide my code is requested. thank you in advance.

Comment: a listView is an instance of AbsListView. This is an anonymous inner class being printed out by some debugging code left in by the manufacturer.

Comment: @Greg Giacovelli,oh. i didn't do my reading correctly then. thank you for informing.

Comment: @GregGiacovelli, but why the page is loading slower then, (it can't be because of the xml file(.xml) because the file is in a folder of the phone) and i also have different adapter for the image. i couldn't say its because of the phone ram because the whole app is working good (fast) but only this listview activity its like that.

Comment: What does **your** code look like? Is it just a copy and paste of the tutorial?

Comment: @GregGiacovelli, thanks for your time. Nfear solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the xml set the height of the ListView to match_parent instead of wrap_content. This should speed up the ListView.

Comment: oh my god! if i knew this would effect.lol. thank you so much..solved a big issue. thanks.

Comment: er no.sorry..the line was bad and i think i clicked twice.. thanks..:)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a definitive answer but it's some true data - I'm placing it here because I found this page trying to Google my error, maybe someone else having my same troubles will find it too.

My app was failing to load and spamming logcat with this 'Get MotionRecognitionManager' message. This project begun life as a copy paste from another app, and I had the following code up the top of my main activity.

```
setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);    
setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR );
```

Obviously it's supposed to set the orientation to portrait and disable the sensor preventing it from going landscape. For reasons I still don't know, maybe the sensor in my tablet is dodgy, but commenting out the second line fixed all my issues.